# Read line by line from two files simultaneously in shell script

Tags: bash, file, shell

I have two files:

One: `/tmp/starting` has following content:

```
15
30
45
```

Two: `/tmp/ending` has following content:

```
22
35
50
```

I want to read these files line by line simultaneously and use them in another command. For Example,

```
sed -n '15,22p' myFilePath
sed -n '30,35p' myFilePath
sed -n '45,50p' myFilePath
```

How Can I do this in Shell Script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the strings that you want from the `paste` command:

```
$ paste -d, starting ending
15,22
30,35
45,50
```

You can use this with your `sed` command as follows:

```
while read range
do 
    sed -n "${range}p" file
done < <(paste -d, starting ending)
```

The construct `<(...)` is called *process substitution*.  The space between the two `<` is essential.

Comment: Nice solution - gets my vote. Note for anyone else reading this that *process substitution* does require `bash` - which is fine as that's what OP tagged.